# Reading a CSV file with graphviz

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, graphviz

The current project I have to do involves reading data from a CSV file and using graphviz to show a visual representation of the data. this is what the code looks like:

```
import graphviz
import pandas
import os
import math

def save_graph_as_jpg(graph, filename):
    graph.save('temp.dot')
    src = graphviz.Source.from_file('temp.dot')
    src.render(filename, format="jpg")
    os.remove(filename)
    os.remove('temp.dot')

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data

df = pandas.read_csv('decisiontree.csv', index_col = "ID") # df is "data frame"

print(df.to_string())
print(df.info)

nodes = []
nodeMap = {None:None}
for index, row in df[::-1].iterrows():
    row = df.index(int[index])

    if isinstance(df.loc[row][3], float) and math.isnan(df.loc[row][3]):
        df.loc[row][3] = None
    if isinstance(df.loc[row][2], float) and math.isnan(df.loc[row][2]):
        df.loc[row][2] = None
    nodeMap[df.loc[row][0]] = Node(df.loc[row][1],nodeMap[df.loc[row][3]], nodeMap[df.loc[row][2]]), nodes.insert(0,df.loc[row][0])

graph = graphviz.Digraph('structs', filename='structs.gv', node_attr={'shape': 'plaintext', 'ordering':'out'})
        
for nodeID in nodes:
    node = nodeMap[nodeID]
    if node.left:
        graph.edge(node.data, node.left.data)
    if node.right:
        graph.edge(node.data, node.right.data)

save_graph_as_jpg(graph, "Decisiontree")
```

When I run it using IDLE, it returns most of the code just fine, but it gets hung up on line 27:

```
row = df.index(int[index])
```

I get a traceback message saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...... line 27, in <module>
    row = df.index[index]
  File "C:\Users......Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5382, in __getitem__
    result = getitem(key)
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I changed it to:

```
row = df.index(int[index])
```

and now I get this as a traceback and index error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users.......CTML AI\Week 3\Lab3.py", line 27, in <module>
    row = df.index(int[index])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `df.index(int(index))`? You're presumably trying to _call_ `int`, not index into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because you tried to use square brackets with the `int` type, which would try to subscript `int` as if it were an array. That doesn't work because int is a type that can't be subscripted.<sup>[1][2]</sup> You probably want to use parentheses instead to cast the type of the `index` variable to integer. Try changing line 27 to

```py
df.index(int(index))
```

1. However, it would work if you had an array named `int`, but naming your variables the same as builtin types or functions is probably not a good idea.
2. As of Python 3.9, some types can be subscripted in type hints, e.g. `list[int]`.

Comment: The problem isn't that `int` is a type, exactly - `list` is also a type, for example, and [since Python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) supports indexing for type annotation purposes: `list[int]`.